# C# How I can hide all Panels exept 3

Tags: c#, hide, panel

Good day, I found some links about this topic but it doesnt working.
I want to make all Panels invisible by clickin on a button execpt of 3 Panels (Menu etc).

The following code I try'd doesnt work:

```
    private IEnumerable<Panel> _panels;
    private IEnumerable<Panel> Panels
    {
        get
        {
        if (_panels = null)
                _panels = new List<Panel>
         {
             Panel1,
             Panel2,
             Panel3,
             // etc...
         }
            return _panels;
        }
    }
    private void HidePanels()
    {
        foreach (var panel in Panels)
            panel.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HidePanels();
        homePanel.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider just not hiding the ones you don't want to hide, instead of hiding all of them?

Comment: The thing is, i have a menu with 16 menubuttons. so I will have 16 panels. and if i click the feedback button for example. i want to show feedbackpanel. if i click the chat button for example, i want to show the chatpanel. But i have 3 panels for my menu they have to stay all the time.

Comment: OK, don't hide those.

Comment: define doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like you want to exclude your three menu panels from the `Panels` list. If you're also using that for something else, make a separate list -- `NonMenuPanels` -- and iterate through that in `HidePanels()`. Rename `HidePanels()` to `HideNonMenuPanels()` just for clarity. You can have any number of different lists that contain different subsets of the whole mess of Panels you created. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: In your `HidePanels` method, you are making ALL panels invisible. As Ed Plunkett suggest, simply don’t turn off the panels you want. All the panels have a unique name. Example: If panel.name = “panel3” don’t make it invisible.

Comment: yea but if i take panel1.Visible = true; etc in the foreach loop. the Programm looks wierd cuz evertime the Programm load the panel1 etc new it looks like: https://gyazo.com/f4fc8b1c911d899152163b208d67a6e7

Comment: Okay i do it very cheap and make all panels invisible in the method which i want to do invisible. very cheap but working:

Comment: I am not following what you are saying. From your post heading _C# How I can hide all Panels exept 3_ , this seems fairly straightforward. Panels are panels, and you have several panels that you want to make visible-invisible depending on some EVENT. Depending on what event triggers will dictate which panels to make visible-invisible. I am not sure I understand what the problem is.